# accept() blocks (with pending connections); Ctrl+C unblocks?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I've written a simple C++ server for my Windows desktop which talks to a mobile app I'm developing.  When the two communicate, the client connects, sends some data, receives data back from the server, then the connection is closed.

However, occasionally, the client will connect, send data, then time out waiting for the server to respond.  In these instances, the server appears to be stuck in the accept() function - despite the client seeing a connection being made (I've also confirmed the successful TCP handshake using Wireshark), accept() continues to block.  Once this has happened, subsequent attempts to connect will meet the same fate - a successful connection, but unresponsive server.

OK, now for the strangest part - when the server is blocked like this and I enter Ctrl+C in the terminal, my server program is not killed, instead it wakes up and processes all the connections which had been made.  What's going on???

Server code (minus some untriggered error checking):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main() {
  WSADATA wsaData;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData))
  struct sockaddr_in sockaddr;
  sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  sockaddr.sin_port = htons(51119);
  SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &sockaddr, sizeof (sockaddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  listen(ListenSocket, 100)
  for(;;) {
    printf("Listening ... ");
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    printf("connected!\n");
    // Receive data from client, send back response ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't done anything like select text on the terminal have you?

Comment: Nope.  Ctrl+C usually kills the program as it should.  Only when accept is hanging does it have this weird behavior ...

Comment: Sounds like your server is not blocked in `accept`, but rather in a `system` call somewhere.  The ^C kills the program run with `system` and not the server, which then continues to the accept call.  Perhaps something in dealing with a previous client connection?  In any case, you're unlikely to get any help without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like UKMonkey was correct, the issue was with the windows terminal.

It seems that clicking inside the terminal triggers a text selection mode which halts running programs once they try to output to the terminal.  When I hit Ctrl+C, this ended the text selection mode, allowing my program to resume ...

This horrible, horrible feature can be disabled unchecking the QuickEdit Mode option in the terminal's Properties.